# Failed connection over cURL to NodeJS Express URL

Tags: php, node.js, curl

I have a VPS hosted with OVH for a NodeJS script. The VPS runs an Express NodeJS script on port 3000 to return a JSON.
I have a web server hosted with GoDaddy for a Website. The the web server hosts my website.

I require the website to access the NodeJS script and retrieve the JSON data that is returned.

I KNOW that the NodeJS script works as I can enter the URL into my web browser and the JSON content is returned and displayed in-browser. I have ALSO hosted my website locally and the site works perfectly. The PHP script successfully retrieves the NodeJS JSON data and no errors occur.

HOWEVER when I upload my website to the GoDaddy web server; my PHP script fails to connect to the OVH VPS and when dumping `curl_error($ch)` i get the error: `Failed to connect to {vps ip} port 3000: Connection refused`.

I've tried altering the URLs prefix "https://", "http://".
I've tried PHP's file_get_contents() with a similar issue arising.

The Express server runs off of:

```
app.use(cors());
app.get("/server/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
    let server = req.params.id;
    ...
    return res.json({ "foo": "bar" });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`>> API Connecting          >> 3000`);
});
```

My PHP script attempts to access the above through:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://{OVH VPS IP}/server/12345678");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($result, true);
```

Id expect $response to be an array of the returned $result however actually
`$result == false`
and
`$response == NULL`

Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: This will be difficult to answer without some more details about your web server. Is the PHP and Node.js on the same server or two different servers? If it's two different servers, you will need to ensure you have CORS enabled on the Node.js side.

Comment: I have edited the NodeJS server to use CORS. However the errors still persist. @mralanlee

Comment: on your VPS do you have nginx running? I'm curious to see if that is managing your current server routes.

Comment: I believe it may actually be an issue on my website hosts side? I've attempted using curl on my local machine to connect to the URL and i've also attempted using curl on my website hosts SSH. My local machine returns the site content; BUT the website hosts SSH returns "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host" @mralanlee

Comment: it's possible, esp if there's something like nginx running in the background that is actually managing upstream resolutions.

Comment: @mralanlee Im genuinely so confused as to why this isnt working. I dont understand as to why curl works on my local machine but not on my web server...

Comment: Maybe the GD server cant connect outbound to the GD edge router.  Can you log into your web server ? If yet, try to telnet out to your NodeJS server on port 3000.

Answer (score 1):

Try specify second argument of below function (the IP address) like so:

```
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log(`>> API Connecting          >> 3000`);
});
```

'0.0.0.0' is listen on all interfaces,

'127.0.0.1' is probably default value, when You don't specify second argument